# Как в Си передать программе параметр с параметрами?

Tags: c++, windows, передача-параметров

Написал такую прогру:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shellapi.h>

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    // NULL, NULL, SW_RESTORE);  
    printf(argv[1]);
    ShellExecute(0, "open", "winword", argv[1], NULL, SW_RESTORE);
    if(argc == 1) {
        printf("Command line has no additional arguments\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Пока в аргументе нет пробела, все замечательно. Как только пробую с пробелами (естественно, аргумент в кавычках) - никого: открывается пусто окно Ворда, даже не с белым фоном, и пишет что, типа, файл с первым словом аргумента не найден. Естественно, не найден, потому что в названии существующего файла после первого слова есть еще. А в консоль-то при этом аргумент пишет целиком!! С одной стороны, и вопрос, как будто банальный: в Гугле отыскивается много ссылок, а, с другой стороны, ничего не помогает. Удалось только выяснить, что для вывода кавычек в консоль из команды

```
printf
```

их нужно экранировать символом `\`.

---

@isnullxbh, мозгов хватило только на это:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shellapi.h>

main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
     //ShellExecute(0, "open", argv[1], NULL, NULL, SW_RESTORE);  
     std::stringstream ss;
     ss << "\"" << argv[1] << "\"";
     //printf(argv[1]);
     const auto arg = ss.str();
     ShellExecute(0, "open", "winword", arg.c_str(), NULL, SW_RESTORE);
     if(argc == 1) {
             printf("Command line has no additional arguments\n");
     return 0;

 }
}
```

Но не работает, где-то не так написал.

Comment: Покажите, как вы запускаете свою программу и как вы добавляете кавычки

Comment: В "прогре" какой-то кусок копипасты затесался в начале функции `main`...

Comment: Fat-Zer, вы зачем изменили название темы на такое? Я имел ввиду вот именно ОДИН параметр, состоящий из  НЕСКОЛЬКИХ СЛОВ,

Comment: Anton Shchyrov, запускаю и перетаскиванием открываемого файла на мой .ехе, и из командной стоки: https://i.postimg.cc/zv46F48S/1.png

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно экранировать аргумент, например, так:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "\"" << argv[1] << "\"";
```

, а уже затем передавать полученный результат в качестве параметра:

```
const auto arg = ss.str();
ShellExecute(0, "open", "winword", arg.c_str(), NULL, SW_RESTORE);
```

Вариант для C:

```
const size_t len = strlen(argv[1]) + 1;

char* buf = malloc(len + 2);
sprintf(buf, "\"%s\"", argv[0]);
printf("result: %s\n", buf);

free(buf);
buf = NULL;
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97595/discussion-on-answer-by-isnullxbh--------).